# How to write selector function in jQuery .siblings()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors, siblings

I'm trying to find all sibling elements using the .siblings([selector]) method. Although i'm not sure how the selector method should be written, or where i'm going wrong with my current selector method.

I have the html:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input class="username" type="text" placeholder="Username" id="username"/>
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="Password">Password</label>
        <input class="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password"/>
    </div>

    <div>
        <button id="login">Login</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

When the button is clicked, if the username or password fields are not entered, I want to add a class to the unfilled elements.
When the button is clicked, the script is run:

```
if (username not entered) {

    jQuery(this).parent('div').siblings(function (a) {
        if (a.children('input').length > 0 && a.children('input')[0].hasClass('username'))
            return true;
        else return false;
    }).addClass('input-empty');

}
```

However this jQuery call returns both the div containing the username field and the div containing the password field. Why does this return the password field if I have specified that it must contain an input tag with the class 'username'?

Comment: you probably want to chain a filter onto the siblings

Answer (score -1):

Look at [the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/):

> ```
> .siblings( [selector ] )
> ```

The method accepts one argument, which is optional, and is a selector.

> **selector**
>   Type: Selector
>   A string containing a selector expression to match elements against.

If you pass a selector, it must be a *string*.

> ```
> jQuery(this).parent('div').siblings(function (a) {
> ```

You are passing a **function**, which is not a string.

---

Use [the `:has()` psuedo-class](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) to select elements with specific descendants.